# Laravel and scopes hate me - Sorry - I don't know how else to phase it

Tags: laravel, scopes

So we have all been there - you are doing something simple that is giving you very odd results and you try everything to understand the issue but you can only conclude that the code hates you! (You know you are overlooking something)

That is me right now...

I have a game with many user and users have to be approved to be actually playing so I have created a playing scope on the User object so I can write statements like:

```
$game->players()->playing()->count();
```

This returns a count of the players who are actually approved to play.

The scope is:

```
public function scopePlaying($query){
    return $query->where('status', Self::APPROVED)
                    ->orderBy('position', 'asc');
}
```

This scope works well, however being approved is not the only condition so I extended the scope to include this other condition:

```
public function scopePlaying($query){
    return $query->where('status', Self::APPROVED)
                    ->where('action', '<>', Self::ACTION_FOLD)
                    ->orderBy('position', 'asc');
}
```

And suddenly the scope returns nothing. Ever. If I change the name of the "action" column to something that does not exist on the table instead of it throwing an error it starts working as it did before adding the new where clause.

Is my computer possessed and is just doing this to make me give up programming forever? What am I missing?

Output from the query log:

```
[2020-06-02 12:29:04] testing.DEBUG: array (
  0 =>
   array (
     'query' => 'select count(*) as aggregate from "users" where "users"."game_id" = ? and "users"."game_id" is not null and "status" = ? and "action" <> ?',
'bindings' =>
array (
  0 => 'c1f666c7-dc6c-47c1-9abc-8decba505ac5',
  1 => 'approved',
  2 => 'fold',
),
'time' => 0.13,
```

),
)

My Migration for the table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('game_id');
        $table->string('name');            
        $table->string('status', 10)->default('online');
        $table->string('action', 10)->nullable();
        $table->smallInteger('position')->nullable();            
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added a similar local scope to a model in one of my projects to replicate:

```php
public function scopeTest($query)
{
    return $query->where('id', '<', 10)->
        where('store_option_id', '<>', 2)->
        orderBy('position', 'asc');
}
```

And the scope works fine for me. I can confirm it doesn't have anything to do with the orderBy clause, or having two where clauses. It could be that your data just doesn't match the where clauses (ie maybe there are no active users that also doesn't have an action of fold). Or maybe 'action' is misspelled in your migration. The best way to debug this would be to execute the query manually on your database.

#### Update:

I'm almost certain there is a typo or something in the code that generates your test data. It's to know what because you haven't posted that code, but I changed all the store_option_id's to NULL and lo and behold: empty set. ***Or maybe** you meant for those fields to be NULL*, **but null doesn't compare to anything in SQL**, see:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

> The NULL value can be surprising until you get used to it. Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated somewhat differently from other values.
>
> To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators

...

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL

So if you want to include rows with NULL action columns you must change your scope as such:

```php
public function scopePlaying($query){
    return $query->where('status', Self::APPROVED)->
            where(function ($query) {
                return $query->
                    where('action', '<>', Self::ACTION_FOLD)->
                    orWhereNull('action');
            });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that as well and wrote a load of tests to test the properties of each user before calling the scope.

Comment: @PaulBarclay I've tried replicating your problem and your scope looks fine. I'm fairly certain it's your data. You should post your test cases and your migrations. And I still strongly suggest running the query manually on your server. Also you should mention the laravel version

Comment: It is related to the NULL default value on the column. I posted an answer. Thanks for the help in going over all this!

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be the fact that my "action" property had the default values of NULL in the database.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('game_id');
    $table->string('name');            
    $table->string('status', 10)->default('online');
    $table->string('action', 10)->nullable();
    $table->smallInteger('position')->nullable();            
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I changed this to have some value and it started working as expected.

It must be the handling of NULL with comparisons and I should have included

```
where action is null OR action <> "fold"
```

I kept the null default and updated the scope.

```
public function scopePlaying($query){
    return $query->where('status', Self::APPROVED)
                    ->whereNull('action')
                    ->orWhere('action', '<>', Self::ACTION_FOLD)
                    ->orderBy('position', 'asc');
}
```

It's pretty scary because I have been using MySQL for nearly 20 years and I can't remember encountering this before.

Or maybe I have and I am so old I have forgotten....